# With R xml2 and purrr how to add id attribute sequencing along in a group?

Tags: r, xml, purrr

I have an xml file that look like this :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)

x <- read_xml('<root>
                <group id= "1">
                  <subgroup>bla</subgroup>
                  <subgroup>bla2</subgroup>
                  <subgroup>bla3</subgroup>
                </group>
                <group id="2">
                  <subgroup>qsdfbla</subgroup>
                  <subgroup>bla2qsdf</subgroup>
                  <subgroup>bla3qfsd</subgroup>
                  <subgroup>qsdfqfsd</subgroup>
                </group>
              </root>')
```

I would like to add an id attribute to all subgroup node, that seq inside each group. I want the first value to be 1, then 2, then 3, then start again at 1 in the second group.

I tried that :

```
x %>%
  xml_find_all('//group') %>%
  map(~xml_children(.) %>% xml_set_attr("idSubGroup",seq_along(.)))
```

but all I manage to do is put 1 in every idSubGroup attribute. How could I really "seq along" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which is basically a loop within a loop.  Find the group nodes then one by one find the children nodes and update each one of them individually.  I don't believe it is possible to vectorize this step.
I used the `lapply` and `sapply` functions here, but could be converted over to the purrr package if desired.

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

x <- read_xml('<root>
              <group id= "1">
              <subgroup>bla</subgroup>
              <subgroup>bla2</subgroup>
              <subgroup>bla3</subgroup>
              </group>
              <group id="2">
              <subgroup>qsdfbla</subgroup>
              <subgroup>bla2qsdf</subgroup>
              <subgroup>bla3qfsd</subgroup>
              <subgroup>qsdfqfsd</subgroup>
              </group>
              </root>')


#find all of the group nodes
groups<-x %>%   xml_find_all('//group')

lapply(groups, function(group){
   #find all of the children nodes in each group
   cnodes<-group %>% xml_children(.)
   #loop through each child node and add subgroup number
   sapply(1:length(cnodes), function(node){cnodes[node] %>% xml_set_attr("idSubGroup",node) })
})

print(x)
# {xml_document}
# <root>
# [1] <group id="1">\n  <subgroup idSubGroup="1">bla</subgroup>\n  <subgroup idSubGroup="2">bla2</subgroup>\n  < ...
# [2] <group id="2">\n  <subgroup idSubGroup="1">qsdfbla</subgroup>\n  <subgroup idSubGroup="2">bla2qsdf</subgro ...
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, if I translate it with purrr, I get : `x %>%
  xml_find_all('//group') %>%
  map(function(x) {
    n <- xml_length(x)
    map(1:n,function(y) {xml_child(x,y) %>% xml_set_attr("idSubGroup",y)})
  })` . I don't find it very pretty but it works ! thanks again